# Iterating with ObjectInputStream.readObject() from a .txt-file

Tags: java, serialization

I am having trouble reading object-data from a .txt-file using the readObject()-method from ObjectInputStream. 
I am writing multiple User-objects to a .txt to save users when the server for the program is down, and the writing works fine, though when I am trying to read the information back, I don't know how to loop through/read the next line in the file.

```
public void readObjectFromFile() {
        boolean cont = true;
        User user;

try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("files/userlist.txt");
            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);


            while(cont){
                Object obj = objectIn.readObject();
                if(obj != null) {
                    registeredUsers.add((User)objectIn.readObject());
                    user = (User)obj;
                    userPasswords.put(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
                    System.out.println(user.getUsername());
                }else {
                    cont = false;
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
}

public void addUserToDatabase(User user) {
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("files/userlist.txt", true);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)){
            oos.writeObject(user);
            oos.write('\n');
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I would want to read the file line-by-line, and store the information of every line in a User-object and store it in the registeredUsers-list.

Comment: `readObject()` does not return null at end of stream. It can do that any time you wrote a null. So stopping at null is invalid. You must catch `EOFException` and break instead. Serialized data is not text and should not be stored in a file named .txt. There is therefore no such thing as 'line by line' either. And don't write newlines in object streams. They accomplish nothing.

Comment: And you can't append to an object atream like that. The second read will encounter another stream header and barf. Keep the file open.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it!

```
public void readUsersFromFile() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("files/userlist.dat");
            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            boolean keepReading = true;
            try {
                while(keepReading) {
                    User user = (User)objectIn.readObject();
                    registeredUsers.add(user);
                    userPasswords.put(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
                    System.out.println(user.getUsername());
                    objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

                }
            }catch(EOFException e) {
                keepReading = false;
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You were given this solution. 'I solved it' is a spurious claim. Don't shred your credibility.

Answer (score -1):

**Problem:** You are reading twice in while loop.

1. First Call:
   objectIn.readObject()
2. Second Call:
   registeredUsers.add((User)**objectIn.readObject()**);

**Solution:**

Do not call readObject() method twice use the reference that is already been taken.

**Other then functional problem, you can also correct the following things to make your code better:**

1. Don't make while loop so complex.
2. No need to use separate boolean counter in while loop.
3. Just typecast once to user not multiple times (at the time of readObject() call itself).

**Please refer following code:**

```
User user = null;
while((user = (User) objectIn.readObject()) != null){
                registeredUsers.add(user);
                userPasswords.put(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
                System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Great input!
I changed the while-loop as you suggested, but I still only read the first object from the file, and I have no idea of how to fix it... :(

Comment: EDIT: I realised where my next problem lies, when writing the to the file I write a linebreak ('\n') after each writeObject, and when I try to read it with the readObject-method it throws an OptionalDataException - any ideas of how I can work around that?

Comment: @RasmusOberg Yes: don't write the newline. It's pointless. This while loop is still incorrect: see my comment under your question.

Comment: Okay, first - don't write the newline, second - don't save the file as .txt?
Could I store it in a .dat-file with? And do I need to indicate where one object stops and anotherone starts when writing to the file? 
Greatly appreciate you helping me!

Comment: @RasmusOberg You can store it in whatever filename you like, but it isn't text, so using .txt is misleading, most of all to yourself, as it led you to do inappropriate things like test for null, add a newline, ... You don't need to indicate where the object stops. It knows.

Answer (score -1):

Are you already getting the data from the file? 
I have done this before with pipe-delimited files ("|"), so: 
value1|value2|value3

Not sure of the makeup of your file, but if you are already reading the data then you can skip to next lines & make new User objects like so:

```
    private List <UserEntry> collectFileContents(InputStream is, String fileName) throws Exception {
    try {
        List <UserEntry> userEntries = new ArrayList <UserEntry>(); 
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.length() > 0) {
                UserEntry entry = new UserEntry();
                try {
                    String[] lineValues = line.split("\\|",-1);
                    entry.setVal1(lineValues[0]);
                    entry.setVal2(lineValues[1]);
                    //etc..
                    userEntries.add(entry);
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  ex) {
                    //error handling here
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return userEntries;
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        //error handling here
    }

}
```

This should create a list of Users, and I save them to the DB in a different method. But you can do it however you like. Also of note - in my file I have a title line as the first line. So this code will skip the first line. Again, not sure about how your file is set up.

Comment: It isn't |-delimited data. It is serialized data. Read the question.